# Precision of std::chrono::duration<double> and double - C++

Tags: c++, c++11, double, mean, c++-chrono

I have stored in a `std::chrono::duration<double>` variable the duration of my algorithm and I want to repeat the experiment a few times (let's say 3 times) so I want to store in a vector the three durations to calculate the mean.

I use a vector of double (storing `time.count()`).

The duration are, more or less,

> 0.003,
>
> 0.004,
>
> 0.003

and when I calculate the mean (using a double) the result is **0**.

Is there anyway to have more precision when calculating the mean?

Comment: can we see the code of that calculation?

Comment: `double sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++)
   sum += times[i].count();

double mean = sum / times.size();`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a loop in the vector so you can calculate the mean.

```
double sum = 0;
//define 3 duration objects and initialize it later
std::chrono::duration<double> a(0.003);
std::chrono::duration<double> b(0.004);
std::chrono::duration<double> c(0.003);
//define a vector of durations
std::vector<std::chrono::duration<double>> times{a, b, c};
//calcuöate the sum of all element in vector
for (auto x : times)
{
    sum += x.count();
}
//calculate mean as double 
double mean = sum / times.size(); 

std::cout << "Mean Duration: " << mean  <<std::endl;
```